# Synchronous calls in javascript, but not handled synchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronous

I am having some issues with synchronous calls, 
and can't seem to understand exactly what's going wrong.

When debugging the code, it fills up the songTracks array perfectly, 
just until the return statement, where it is empty again.

Code sample:

```
function getAllSongIds(lijstId){
  var songTracks = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://somehost.com/lists/"+lijstId+"/editions/",   
      dataType: "jsonp",
      async: false,
      success: function(json){

        for (i in json.editions) {
          $.ajax({
            url:"http://somehost.com/lists/"+lijstId+"/editions/"+json.editions[i].id,
            dataType:"jsonp",
            async: false,
            success: function(json2){
              for(j in json2.tracks){
                if(songTracks.indexOf(json2.tracks[j].id) === -1){
                  songTracks.push(json2.tracks[j].id);
                }
              }
            }
          })
        };
      }

    });
  alert(songTracks);
  return songTracks;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to the lands of callback hell, and looping XHR calls. I suggest you check out jQuery's promise feature. The issue is is that your code does not wait for the XHR to return, it moves on, so your success function is skewed by the delay

Comment: Didn't even read that async:false. My bad

Comment: [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) ***cannot*** be made sync by using `async:false`

Comment: Didn't read the JSONP part...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**JSONP** is always asynchronous. The `async: false` setting is simply ignored.  From the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> [...] If you need synchronous requests, set this option to `false`. Cross-domain requests and `dataType: "jsonp"` requests do not support synchronous operation.

**Why?**

JSONP has actually nothing to do with Ajax. jQuery is just providing a single function to deal with both. JSONP is nothing else but appending a `<script>` element to the document. The browser will load these scripts asynchronously.

See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) for possible (asynchronous) solutions.